# SQL Optimization using Table Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have an old stored procedure which takes over 3 minutes to complete.

Something like this:

```
Select * 
from Table A
left Job Table B on A.ID = B.PID
Where 
    ...
    A.StartDate > @Date1 
    And A.EndDate < @Date2
```

One reason for slowness is that table A has over 20 million rows.

Both tables have proper indexing applied.

To fix this I created a table variable (same structure as table A) and filled it with

```
Select * 
From TableA  
Where A.StartDate > @Date1 
  And A.EndDate < @Date2
```

Then I joined this table variable with table B.

The script runs much faster now.

Do you see a potential pitfall in my approach?

Comment: The table is not being updated.  I would look at the execution plans for the two queries and try to mimic the better plan directly on the table itself.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff  Tnx for the reply. Not sure what you mean by 'The table is not being updated'. The main reason for the speed increase in my case was Table Variable now has 4000 rows instead of 20 million. any Drawbacks?

Comment: Why you're using `*`? and why you need a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Just for your info, My Stored procedure is all select statements,

Comment: @Sami. that was just a quick example for here. The actual script contains column names. I also tired join, speed did not increase?

Comment: Table Variables don't have statistics. In most versions of SQL Server, the plan optimizer will assume the table variable has exactly one row, which can lead to really bad plans if you have a lot of rows in there. Also, the only index you can put on a Table Variable is a primary key. Depending on how you use it, that may not be enough. You might consider a temp table instead, with appropriate indexes added. This is just FYI. I use temp tables if I expect more than two dozen rows, give or take.

Comment: There are many approaches to optimizing a stored procedure.  There are many problems that could result from a bad approach.  You will need to provide more specific information.

Comment: @SNash . . . The table variable is not being updated.  That might not be a consideration, but I could imagine situations where you load the table variable but still want the most recent transactions somewhere in the stored procedure.

Comment: @ Gordon Linoff  Good point. In my case, I'm not in a fast transaction environment.

Comment: I am curious as to how many rows you have in Table B. If you are left joining it, you are basically saying you want all the data from the left, plus matching data from rows on the right (table B). Could it be that the evaluation of that is occurring before the final WHERE clause? One way to test this might be to remove the where condition and make it an additional join on condition? I am a little stumped though. The optimizer should be handling this no problem. What version SQL server are you using?

Comment: About 175000 rows. I think the evaluation of join occurring BEFORE the final WHERE clause and this the source of the problem

Comment: Oh I think I see. So the concern is that there are so many updates happening at a time that the locks have to release before the query is satisfied? If so, the approach seems sound. But I would use a temp table vs temp variable if your initial population is above 10k rows. Another option could be to use a (NOLOCK) hint next to the initial table and join table. However, if you do that, it will be a dirty read that could include records that were about to update... thus those rows would be stale. But with as rapid as things change, wouldn't even a LOCKING select be stale after a few seconds?

Comment: Thanks. Our database is not dynamic at all. So yes I will include NOLOCK hint so see I get better performance.

Comment: Thanks all, I see good answers in the comments above. If you write an answer I will accept it.

Comment: See [Bad Habits to kick - putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/) - it is *not recommended* to use this everywhere - quite the contrary!

Comment: @Marc_s  Thanks.